# Angular Grunt Uglification Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:»

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Assuming 'id' is a predefined dynamic variable; why would this not minify correctly?

```
 var uniqueVariable = 'device_' + id;
 $scope[uniqueVariable] = {uniqueVariable};
```

Here is the specific message from grunt-contrib-uglify:

> Warning: Uglification failed.
>   Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:».

Comment: The dependency injector has problems with minified js (tho that might not be the issue here). You need to show more code before I can help.

Comment: Is this code correct? Shouldn't be `{ uniqueVariable: uniqueVariable }`or just `uniqueVariable without "{" "}"?

Comment: Felippe, that actually turned out to be the issue. There needs to be a key-pair value here, I can't just put any arbitrary string here like I had assumed.

Answer (score 0):

As Felippe Duarte pointed out, there needs to be a key-pair value, I can't just put any arbitrary string here like I had assumed.